# Return result of select distinct query inside function

Tags: postgresql

I have some code that takes a name and outputs different variations of it, ie Michael and Mike. The query works fine like this:

```
with recursive v(text) as (
        LOGIC REMOVED
)
select distinct(text) from v;
```

and it returns something like this:

```
    text    
------------
 john jim
 john james
```

I'm trying to package this up in a function, but struggling at how to return the two values as a setof text. This is what I have:

```
begin;
create or replace function variant_generator(orig_name text) returns setof text as
$$
begin
with recursive v(text) as (
        LOGIC REMOVED
)
return query (select distinct(text) from v);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Can anyone advise what I should do to get this returned as expected?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `returns table` and `language sql`:

```
create or replace function variant_generator(orig_name text) 
  returns table ("text" text)
as
$$
with recursive v(text) as (
    LOGIC REMOVED
)
select distinct text 
from v;
$$ 
language sql;
```

With PL/pgSQL (which isn't necessary here), you would need to write the `return query` before the *complete* query - that is before the `WITH` clause:

```
$$
begin
  return query 
    with recursive v(text) as (
        LOGIC REMOVED
    )
    select distinct text 
    from v;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```